# AVPlayer forward class declaration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video

So I have this `AVPlayerViewController` nested inside a container view in my storyboard. I access this player vide controller using `prepareForSegue`. But when I attempt to set any properties on the `player` property of it, Xcode gives me an error `Receiver 'AVPlayer' for class message is a forward declaration`. I have AVKit correctly imported in the `.h`. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {  
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"videoPlayerEmbed"]) {
        self.videoPlayerController = (AVPlayerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        self.videoPlayerController.delegate = self;
        self.videoPlayerController.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
    } else {
        [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured it out. I thought `#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>` was enough for AVPlayerViewController but if you want to manage the `AVPlayer` you also need `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported `AVPlayerViewController.h` i.e. `#import "AVPlayerViewController.h"`?

A forward declaration is where the you are trying to send messages to a class that the compiler doesn't know about.

Comment: I get `'AVPlayerViewController.h' file not found` now.

Comment: @TechGenius Make sure your Project > General > Linked Framework and Libraries includes AVKit.framework and AVFoundation.framework